# Customizing theme for buttons

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add a default theme for my buttons in my flutter app. I want a bg color, text color, and borderRadius amount. I tried doing the following, but the only thing that worked was the borderRadius.

```
theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.red,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        ),
        buttonColor: Colors.orange,
      )),
```

I want the bg color to be `primaryColor`, but for some reasone when I do `buttonColor: primaryColor`, I get an error.

Comment: Do you understand why you get that error?

Comment: @nvoigt No. Should I not be able to access the themeData?

Comment: Why would you? Your attempted syntax would not work in *any* programming language, including the one's you already know looking at your profile. Flutter cannot do magic that others cannot. It's still basic computing rules.

Comment: By the way, please provide a [mcve], we have no idea how you even see whether it "works" or not.

Comment: @nvoigt My intention is, I want to define the button styles once, and reuse the same style throughout the project. Do you know of a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use primarySwatch Tag for buttonColor.

```
theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.red,
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
)),
```